# Why do these variables have different types in this generic method?

Tags: java, generics, queue

How come "result" is created with simply "T", but "temp" is created with "`Queue<T>`", does it matter?

```
// returns the item at the front of the given queue,
  without 
     // removing it from the queue
     public static <T> T peek(Queue<T> q) 
     throws NoSuchElementException {
        /** COMPLETE THIS METHOD **/
        if (q.isEmpty()) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException("Queue Empty");
        }
        T result = q.dequeue();

        Queue<T> temp = new Queue<T>();
        temp.enqueue(result);

        while(!q.isEmpty()) {
           temp.enqueue(q.dequeue());
        }

        while(!temp.isEmpty()) {
           q.enqueue(temp.dequeue());
        }
        return result;
     }
```

Answer (score 2):

The types of `result` and `temp` are different because they represent different types of things. Let's look at this code:

```
T result = q.dequeue();
```

Here, the sort of thing that we're storing in `result` is whatever type of thing gets handed back when you dequeue from the queue `q`. So what type of things does `q` store? Looking at the parameters, we see that `q` is a `Queue<T>`, meaning that each element in the queue is of type `T`. Therefore, we need to give `result` the type `T`, since it represents a single element taken out of the queue.

On the other hand, when we write

```
Queue<T> temp = new Queue<T>();
```

the goal is to create a new `Queue` that can hold objects of type `T`. To do that, we need to tell Java that we want it to be a `Queue<T>`.

The reason that this is different from when we declared `result` is that we're trying to do fundamentally different things. `result` is designed to hold a single item, which has type `T` in this case. `temp` is designed to store a collection of items, so we make it a `Queue<T>` to indicate that it's not just a single `T`, but rather a queue of them.

Hope this helps!

Comment: That makes so much more sense, I wan't looking at T like I would a int or float etc, thanks!